# Clear all project property values in SoapUI using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

Within soapUI, I'm using multiple groovy scripts to write values to the Project Level so that multiple test suites can pull data during a test run. At the end of the run, I would like to use a Groovy script that removes all the values (not the placeholders) from project properties. I tried using the clearPropertyValues(), but get an error. I do not think I'm setting up my script correctly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you want to remove the `custom properties` values from your project, keeping the property names. IMO the correct place to do so is using `groovy` in the `tearDown script` of your project, so you can go to `navigator` window on the SOAPUI and double click in your project, it opens the project config pop up, then select the `testSuites` tab and click on `testDown script`, there you can place the follow `groovy` code which set the properties of your project to empty string (to keep the `placeholders`):

```
// for each property in the project level 
project.getPropertyNames().each{ propName ->
    log.info "remove prop: $propName"
    // set it's value as an empty string
    project.setPropertyValue(propName,'')
}
```

Note that `tearDown script` will be executed each time all your testSuites are finish from project execution.

[image]

Hope it helps,

Comment: OP said he wants to clear the values, but not remove the "placeholders". I read that as: `project.setPropertyValue(propName, "")`, instead of the `removeProperty()`?

Comment: @SiKing this is due my low english skills... I didn't understand what `placeholders` means in this context. Thank you `:)`

Comment: It's only a guess on my part, but I think he wants to leave the parameters, just set them to blank. Your English is fine! :)

Comment: Thank you very much @albciff!!! That was exactly what I needed. Great explanation too!!! Also, @SiKing, I appreciate your input and looking out for my solution! I can't thank you guys enough. This was perfect!!!

Comment: @GrantEdwards nice to help you `:)`